# Disallow editing a cell once there is an entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a log book where:

- Once the operator enters information that cell should lock.
- A date and time for the entry should auto populate.

I have tried several codes I found on bulletin boards, but nothing works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
        For i = 2 To 1000
            If Cells(i, "B").Value <> " " And Cells(i, "B").Value = " " Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Date & " " & Time
                Cells(i, "A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Range("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If Cells(i, "B").Value <> " " And Cells(i, "B").Value = " "   -when is that TRUE? :)

Comment: My spreadsheet is only 2 columns.  First is Date and Time, second is where data is entered.  Didn't know how to write this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the above comment again. You have `If A <> B And A = B Then` -- the two predicates are mutually exclusive, the condition will always be false.

Comment: So what would I use to auto populate column A with the date and time, when something is entered in Column B, also locking this date and time, so it won't change?  I am very new to this VBA.  Thanks.

Comment: This is where I got some of the code, tried to alter to my situation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574399/how-to-get-excel-spreadsheet-to-auto-populate-date-time-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

In the same [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574399/how-to-get-excel-spreadsheet-to-auto-populate-date-time-using-vba) you have a solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim bc As Range   'no sense in declaring something until we actually need it
        For Each bc In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) 'deal with every cell that intersects. This is how to handle pastes into more than one cell
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(bc.Row, "B")) Then
                Cells(bc.Row, "A").Value = Now 'Now is the equivalent of Date + Time
                Cells(bc.Row, "A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
            End If
        Next bc
        'Range("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit 'this slows things down. you may want to comment this out and just set an apprpriate column width that will handle everything
    End If
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I just addpat for your case on Range B:B.

Hope it helps